# Alert Selected users SignalR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am looking into an alternative solution to my `jQuery` and `Ajax` alerting feature in my `MVC4` app. I have stumbled across `SignalR` which looks like it can solve my solution but where I hear you can broadcast to a certain client and not all, I cannot seem to find an example.

Basically all I want to know is:

1. On set up can the clientID be the applications UserID on login?
2. Are you able to broadcast to specific roles and/or a list of userID's
3. Are there are any examples that can help demonstrate the above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to check out the jabbr application written by the signalr team.  https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/tree/master/JabbR

Comment: Is this VS2012? I cant seem to open it.

Comment: Yes, it is VS2012 and works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With SignalR you can manage your own user identities.  SignalR represents each user with a ConnectionId but it is ultimately up to the dev to map that to an existing user profile.
2. Yes, you are able to broadcast to groups or specific clients.  You can add clients to groups and then send single messages to multiple people simultaneously or you can send to a specific client.
3. As noted in the comment JabbR is an excelent example.  Also for a quick start on getting introduced to SignalR check out the [Quick Start Hubs page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs).  Lastly SignalR is open source so check out the [source](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) and the [wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will this connectionID change every time per connection and can it be set on setting up the connection? I.e. connection.ConnectionID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserID?

Comment: The connection ID will change for every connection (it's a GUID) and no you cannot set it on the connection setup.  I'd recommend making a static ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile> on your hub where UserProfile is your own data structure that contains a users WebSecurity identity etc.  In Onconnected add to the dictionary, in OnReconnected check if the users is there; if he is not then add him, in OnDisconnected remove the user from the dictionary.